# How to select a distinct list of elements contained in another list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code

```
new Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<Control>>()
{
    { "view1", new Control[] { contents, building, view1 }},
    { "view2", new Control[] { contents,  view2 }},
    { "view3", new Control[] { building,  view3 }
}
```

How do I get a list of all the distinct controls using linq?

The result should be:

```
{
    contents,
    building,
    view2,
    view3
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var distinct = dictionary.Values.SelectMany(x => x)
                                .Distinct();
```

I've decided to keep this answer despite Marc having an equivalent one - it's instructive to see both approaches. In my approach we take the sequence of values - each of which is an `IEnumerable<Control>` and flatten it by saying, "For each value, we want to obtain an `IEnumerable<Control>` just by taking that vaule."

Marc's approach takes the sequence of key/value pairs and flattens that saying, "For each pair, we want to obtain an `IEnumerable<Control>` by taking the value of the pair."

In both cases, `SelectMany` takes the sequence of result sequences, and flattens them into a single sequence - so the result *before* the `Distinct()` call is effectively the sequence `{ contents, building, view1, contents, view2, building, view3 }`. The `Distinct` call will then yield the sequence `{ contents, building, view1, view2, view3 }`.

Comment: Well, if you're going to go and *explain* things ;p My reasoning is that maybe the pair approach has less indirection (via `ValueCollection` etc). But either will work.

Comment: Thanks everybody,
  I have given Jon the credit as he explained it, as I cannot determine who posted first. Sorry Marc. 

Podge

Answer (score 6):

```
var controls = yourDictionary.SelectMany(pair => pair.Value).Distinct();
```

Comment: Marc Gravell vs Jon Skeet, what a battle! :)

Comment: @Andrey - even *if* I occasionally win the odd "battle", I think we know who owns the war ;p

Answer (score 1):

```
var distinctControls = dictionary.Values.SelectMany(x=>x).Distinct();
```